# MSSQL - comma-delimited string values into new table

Tags: sql-server

A problem dealing with comma-delimited values in MSSQL Server.

I've got a Table-1 with two columns.

`COL1` holds strings with values comma separated:

```
  'a,b,c,...'
  'w,x,y,...'
```

`COL2` holds `INT`s.

So data looks like this:

```
  |   COL1   |   COL2   |
  |'a,b,c,..'|    4     |
  |'w,x,y,..'|    5     |
```

I need a new Table-2 of two columns with each (comma-delimited) value from `COL1` of Table-1 in it's own row, along with the corresponding `INT` value from Table-1 `COL2`. Like so:

```
  | 'a'  | 4 |
  | 'b'  | 4 |
  ...
  | 'w'  | 5 |
  | 'x'  | 5 |
  ...
```

This would be a cinch in a procedural language, but I don't have a clue how to get the required output from SQL, and my output needs to be gotten directly from a query (for an Oracle Business Server).

Appreciate any advice. A good direction-pointing hint should do it for me. Two days of internet searching haven't gotten me where I need to be.

Comment: Your best bet will be to code this procedural, i. e. in a user defined function or stored procedure, like e. g. described here: http://www.codenutz.com/useful-sql-split-to-table-functions-for-csv/

Comment: Why you have that kind of ugly table?

Comment: @Hamlet because JSON roolz

Comment: @Hamlet manipulating data from NMS with SQL Server, and row-space is limited in the NMS. It's ugly but it's love :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
    (
        @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Delim VARCHAR(255)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
        RETURN ( SELECT [Value] FROM 
          ( 
            SELECT 
              [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
              CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
            FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
              FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
              WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
              AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
          ) AS y
        );
```

Now:

```
SELECT Col1 = s.Value, Col2 = t1.COL2
--  INTO dbo.[Table-2]
FROM dbo.[Table-1] AS t1
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitString(t1.COL1, ',') AS s;
```

When you are happy with the output, uncomment the `-- INTO` to generate the new table.

Comment: looks like a beautiful solution - didn't know there WAS a CROSS APPLY. Super!